# Documentation of a table of database

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can anyone suggest me the right way to begin with the documentation of the table of database I am working on. What actually I need to show to the evaluator?

Comment: I had to create a documentation of a database given to me..means i need to explain the relations between the table,how the foreign keys are used and like that only...so i need the way to begin with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open SQL Server Management studio.

Then paste your table name, select the table name and then press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. You will get all the details of the table as shown below in the image.

[image]

Comment: sorry but whatever is getting displayed,I couldn't get it??